# How can I send or store an arbitrary text message to another EOS account?

Tags: smart-contract

I wan't to be able to send a text string to another EOS account. How can this be done? Are there any mobile wallets that support this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can send arbitrary text messages to any account using the [`require_recipient()`](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/reference#section-require_recipient) function. This function will introduce an inline action that communicates the parameters passed to the action to the desired recipient.

Example contract:

**send_messages.cpp**

```
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>
#include <string>

using eosio::contract;
using std::string;

class send_messages : contract {
    public:
        send_messages(account_name account) : contract(account) {};

        void send(account_name account, string message) {
            require_recipient(account);
        }
};

EOSIO_ABI(send_messages, (send));
```

Afterwards, pushing an action to the contract as follows:

```
$ cleos push action <account-name> send '["<recipient>", "message"]' -p <acount-name>
```

would send the string `"message"` to the `<recipient>` in the form of an action.

---

In regards to wallet support for this, you only need a software that allows you to push actions to your contract, which would be enough as long as you publish your contract on the blockchain first.

---

> what is the max character limit? and what is the cost of sending 1K, 10K, and 100KB text message.

There's not really a hard max character limit, as you can send as many strings of `max_size()` as you want. However, to process larger strings, you need more CPU and NET staked, but these resources are a bit impractical to approximate right now, especially as EOS renting systems would make this cheaper.

### Naive calculation

However, if you want a back of the envelope calculations, perhaps you'd need to have staked about **0.01 EOS / 10,000 bytes message / day at current rates.**

Explanation:

### NET

For NET you'd need approximately as many bytes the message has + ~100bytes (e.g. you'd need 10,100 bytes to send a 10,000 bytes message.) According to [eosrp.io](https://eosrp.io), the price right now is 0.00050833 EOS/KiB/Day, so perhaps you'd look at **0.005 EOS / 10,000 bytes message / day for NET**

### CPU

This depends on the BP, the load, etc, and it's highly volatile, but I just tried to make such a transaction on Jungle testnet, and I got 2,000us. At current price of 0.00269295 EOS/ms/Day, that'd be **~0.005 EOS / 10,000 bytes message / day for CPU**

Comment: what is the max character limit? and what is the cost of sending 1K, 10K, and 100KB text message.

Comment: @Patoshiパトシ updated my answer to include some cost discussion, but i wouldn't put too much thought in these estimates for now as the network keeps changing