# Can I send 0.000 EOS transaction using cleos with a memo field in json format

Tags: cleos

I am interested in writing a small dApp that interacts with a web API such that a 0.0000 EOS transaction with JSON memo field needs to be stored per transaction.

To test this concept, I tried the scatter desktop but it refuses to send 0.0000 EOS transaction. I used to have a cleos set up on a VM but recently removed it so cannot test it on my own in the next 24 hours.

Comment: So far I heard from @NathanJames that token contract does not allow 0.0000 amount.

Answer (score 3):

No, the [`transfer`](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/contracts/eosio.token/eosio.token.cpp#L78) function checks that the amount transferred is greater than 0:

```
eosio_assert( quantity.amount > 0, "must transfer positive quantity" );
```

You can still send actions with messages to other accounts without transferring EOS by using inline actions which passes the params of the function it's called from (e.g. see [this answer](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/2572/how-can-i-send-or-store-an-arbitrary-text-message-to-another-eos-account/2605#2605))

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to send 'memo' without any token. The way to write memo in EOS block, First, send 0.0001 EOS with 'memo'
Second, send any token with 'memo'
Third, use smart contract such like eosforumtest